# Same blade component showing correctly in one view and not showing image from public folder in other views

Tags: php, laravel, components, laravel-8, laravel-blade

I'm building a website using Laravel 8 where i have one component called app.blade.php.

This component is the body of the project and includes the navbar.

The problem that i'm facing is that this compenent is correctly showing in every view, while in a view called article.blade.php it is showing but without showing the logo image, only the ALT text.

I have also tried to use other images in the view but no one of these images is showing, while on the other views everything is correct.

The images at the moment are in the public folder, later i will move everything to the storage.

Here's my component

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300;400;500&family=Readex+Pro:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    {{-- Icone --}}

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-10/jx2EXwxxWqCLX/hHth/vu2KY3jCF70dCQB8TSgNjbCVAC/8vai53GfMDrO2Emgwccf2pJqxct9ehpzG+MTw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Glide.js/3.2.0/css/glide.core.css" integrity="sha512-ShLuspGzRsTiMlQ2Rg0e+atjy/gVQr3oYKnKmQkHQ6sxcnDAEOtOaPz2rRmeygV2CtnwUawDyHkGgH4zUbP3Hw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <x-navbar/>

        <main>
            {{$slot}}
        </main>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Glide.js/3.2.0/glide.js" integrity="sha512-vZGsugWaSqQZuW8N5Z3ild7Tk8NqiZjKffeIQGpnnIs6g7HVZaFZjlLKPIw1qDsrQ5KAxAGfBinglQWu6i/8DA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's how i'm calling it :

```
<x-app></x-app>
```

Does anybody has any idea on what it can depends? For me sound strange that it's correctly working on every other view.

Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the code that displays the image, you are probably using a path that is *relative* to the current route.

The image needs to be loaded with an absolute path (starts with `/`) or by using the `asset()` helper.

As you don't show the offending code, its hard to give specific advice